# Login system React JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, backend

That's my code for backend of my app, creating account working very well but i dont know how to implement login system. Can someone help me? **app.post(/login) <- here it starts**
I have idea how it'll be works but i don't know how to do it. My idea is, get username and password from inputs, check if that exist in database, if it is go to dashboard, if not show error.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'root',
    host: 'localhost',
    password: 'my_password',
    database: 'myplan_database'
});

app.post('/create', (req, res) => {

    const username = req.body.username
    const mail = req.body.mail
    const password = req.body.password

    db.query(
        'INSERT INTO users (username, mail, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', 
        [username, mail, password], (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send('Values Insterted')
            }
        }
    );
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    const username = res.db.username
    const password = res.db.password

    db.query(
        
    );
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server is running')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the below code. Hope this code snippet will help you.

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  // Capture the input fields
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  // Ensure the input fields exists and are not empty
  if (username && password) {
    // Execute SQL query that'll select the account from the database based on the specified username and password
    db.query(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?",
      [username, password],
      function (error, results, fields) {
        // If there is an issue with the query, output the error
        if (error) throw error;
        // If the account exists
        if (results.length > 0) {
          // Authenticate the user
          req.session.loggedin = true;
          req.session.username = username;
          // Redirect to home page
          res.redirect("/dashboard");
        } else {
          res.send("Incorrect Username and/or Password!");
        }
        res.end();
      }
    );
  } else {
    res.send("Please enter Username and Password!");
    res.end();
  }
});
```

Comment: Really helpful bro, but i've got another obstacle. What can i do with that for good working?

const login = () => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login',{
            
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Succes')
        })